# Replace string in var

Tags: python

I am using below code to replace a string, it is actually working, I want to know if there is better way to do it ? I just want to read data coming from serial, if it is same value do nothing but if it is new value print it...

```
new = ""
old = ""

while True:
    new = readQR("/dev/input/event7")
    if new != old:
        print (new)
        old = ""
        old = new
        new = ""
    else:
        new = ""
```

Comment: Couple of comments in here, in python you don't need to set the variable as empty in order to assign a new value, you could just do:
`old = new` you don't need `old=""` and `new=""` also the `else` block is not needed

Comment: please explain the expecetd *working* behaviour.

Comment: instead of the three lines you're using to swap old and new, you could do it in just one line, `old, new = new, ""`

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are new to Python. In case you already now these then it might help others :)

You can trim down your code to this:

```
new = ""
old = ""

while True:
    new = readQR("/dev/input/event7")
    if new != old:
        old, new = (new, "")  # tuple unpacking
```

We don't need to do `new = ""` in `else` condition as it would be overwritten by `readQR` in the next iteration.

**Brief explanation of `old, new = (new, "")`:**

Here what we are doing is that we are creating a `tuple` - `(new, "")` and unpacking it in `old` and `new`.

This example might help in understanding the concept of **tuple unpacking**-

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>>
>>> t = a, b  # t is a tuple
>>> t
(1, 2)
>>>
>>> b, a = t  # tuple unpacking - same as b = t[0] and a = t[1]
>>> b
1
>>> a
2
```

You can refer to this video - [Tuples & Tuple Unpacking in Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaswEEqcgv0)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it doesnt give me any output ;

new = ""
old = ""

while True:
    new = readQR("/dev/input/event7")
    if new != old:
        old, new = (new, "")
        print (new)

as I want to change old value with new value and if it is same value do nothing...

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out based on AnirudhSharma's answer:

```
old, new = ("", "")

while True:
    new = readQR("/dev/input/event7")
    if new != old:
        old = new
        print (new)
```

Comment: Nice that you got it working and welcome to Stack Overflow :)